# Event Grid Events Ending with GenericError

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

**Objective**

I'm currently trying to send events to a V1 Azure Function via an HTTP trigger. I have verified that connection between Event Grid and the Function works by successfully receiving the initial Auth handshake that occurs when you first create an event subsription on the portal.

**Problem**

The strange thing is that any real events that get sent to the grid end up in a state called `GenericError`. I cannot seem to find any documentation as to what this means. Even stranger is that an event will hit my azure function *very* intermittently. Once I delete the subscription I always get one successfuly event that hits my function at the time of the deletion.
[image]

**Question**
Does anyone know what this `GenericError` means or what could be causing this issue?

Comment: This is really messed up.. Just set a dead letter queue up and some how that is sparking events to finally enter my function. I suspect some type of issue with event grid itself when debugging locally via ngrok

Comment: what is the Delivery Event Schema? Are you using a Cloud Event Schema or default one such as the Event Grid Schema?

Comment: Hello Roman, I'm using `EventGrid` schema. I tested by deploying to azure and assaulting my function with events and it did not miss one event. It seems theres something going on with NGROK